# /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages directory empty

Tags: python

When I cd into the /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages directory, there is only a README file. Where are all the third-party modules I installed such as sklearn?

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv? Try `find -iname {name-of-a-module-you-installed}` in your home dir or in usr

Comment: "find -iname sklearn" resulted in the following error message: "find: illegal option -- i"

Answer (score 2):

Probably you installed the packages for a different version of python, or you installed them locally (in your home dir, not system-wide).

Inside a Python shell, type this:

```
import sklearn
print (sklearn.__file__)
```

That will tell you where the package is located.

Comment: when i do what you said I get the following error message: "ImportError: No module named sklearn"

Comment: so pip installed my third-party libraries for another python version